# Automated Market Makers - Liquidity Pool - Question about the calculation

Tags: javascript, python, r, logic, cryptocurrency

Esteemed,
I would like to code all the steps for the correct calculation of a pool balance according to Uniswap V2 logic.
Anyone who knew how to help can write in any programming language (Python, Javascript etc.), in this example I used R.
The balancing process for a liquidity pool can be seen here: [example1](https://miro.medium.com/max/2000/1*iSxWe1qvy1yZPKuPlebpkQ.png) and [example2](https://2eguue18ymh52albtja2v96c-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/image_2020-06-29_17-39-02.png).
However, it is not clear how to do it taking into account the Uniswap fee which is 0.3% for every trade.

```
library(tidyverse)
##### INITIAL PARAMETERS
#Uniswap charges users a flat 0.30% fee for
#every trade that takes place on the platform and 
#automatically sends it to a liquidity reserve
Uniswap.fee <- 0.30 / 100

ETH.initial.price <- 100
ETH.pool.price    <- 100

BNT.initial.price <- 1
BNT.pool.price    <- 1

##### INITIAL SITUATION

BNT.units <- 1000
BNT.total <- BNT.units * BNT.initial.price

ETH.units <- BNT.total / ETH.initial.price
ETH.total <- ETH.units * ETH.initial.price

Pool.Value <- BNT.total + ETH.total
Pool.DF <- data.frame(Symbol = c("BNT", "ETH"), Share = c(BNT.total,ETH.total))
ggplot(Pool.DF, aes(x = Symbol, y=Share, fill=Symbol)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, position = "dodge", stat="identity") + labs(title="Initial POOL")
```

[image]

```
##### FINAL SITUATION

ETH.final.price   <- 120
ETH.pool.price    <- 100
BNT.final.price   <- 1
BNT.pool.price    <- 1

##### Imbalanced.Pool
Imbalanced.Pool <- data.frame(Symbol = c("BNT", "ETH"), 
                              Share = c(BNT.total,ETH.units * ETH.final.price ))
ggplot(Imbalanced.Pool, aes(x = Symbol, y=Share, fill=Symbol)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, position = "dodge", stat="identity")+ labs(title="Imbalanced POOL: ETH valorization")

#### need to balance:
```

[image]

...
Now I don't know how to continue the steps to correctly balance and obtain the impermanent loss and arb profit values.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

For DeFi protocols using automated market makers, we implement a pool of a pair of assets (for example, BTC-USDT), and we price the two assets simply with:

b * u = constant

Here b is the amount of BTC in the pool, and u is the amount of USDT. Besides, the constant is often written as `K` in many papers.
Now assume that you want to swap an amount of b' BTC to USDT. You give the b' BTC to the DeFi protocol, and the protocol finds that it should reduce the amount of USDT (which will be given to you) in order to keep b * u = constant. Then with simple calculations, the pool decides to give you u' USDT so that:
(b+b')*(u-u') = constant

With this transaction (assuming that no 0.3% fee is accrued), you obtain u' USDT by giving b' BTC.

Then it comes to the 0.3% fee. When you give b' BTC to the pool, the pool acts as if you give only the deducted amount b'' == 99.7% * b'. Then the pool computes u'' so that

(b+b'')*(u-u'') = constant

In actual computation there are always errors due to limited number of decimals (you can only receive 0.1272 USDT instead of 0.127272727272...). Therefore, the asserted constant can be slowly increasing as more and more swap transactions are executed. This slowly increase the volume of the liquidity pool. Note that the accrued 0.3% fee may not serve as part of the liquidity pool.

For codes, I would use the codes of Flamingo as an example.

First you initialize a swap through FlamingoSwapRouter. You give your sold tokens to the router
https://github.com/flamingo-finance/flamingo-contract-swap/blob/74e61f8406f9e8ededed72f9cb7e0139091ae17c/Swap/flamingo-contract-swap/FlamingoSwapRouter/FlamingoSwapRouterContract.cs#L237

Then the router `SafeTransfer` your sold token to its swapping pairContract, and call the `swap` method of the swapping contract to give you the token you buy.
https://github.com/flamingo-finance/flamingo-contract-swap/blob/74e61f8406f9e8ededed72f9cb7e0139091ae17c/Swap/flamingo-contract-swap/FlamingoSwapPair/FlamingoSwapPairContract.cs#L140
You can see the code `var balance0Adjusted = balance0 * 1000 - amount0In * 3;` which adjusts the assumed amount of token in the liquidity pool. There is a slightly exeeding amount of token in the liquidity pool which are accrued fees, not part of the liquidity.

Answer (score 0):

Across automated market makers, the prices of assets stored within the smart contract are enforced by the "constant product." This is represented through the formula x * y = k, where x and y represent the quantity of tokens you provide liquidity for.

The product of the quantities of the tokens you are providing liquidity for (k) remains the same regardless of market forces, meaning that when there is demand for either asset, the price a market taker will get for the asset is deterministic (ignoring gas fees & slippage). If a buyer of an asset would like to buy 10 of asset "x," the price at which they buy will be determined based on the quantity of "y" they need to supply to keep "k" the same as it was before the trade is made.

With this principle in mind, we can answer your question about how to continue the steps to correctly balance and obtain the impermanent loss and arb profit values; we can do so in Python. Remember, when you begin liquidity providing, the $VALUE of each token needs to be = to the other.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

def ethq_amm_simulation(_ethp, _k):
  return np.sqrt(_k/_ethp)

def bntq_amm_simulation(_ethq, _k):
  return _k/_ethq

df["ethp"] = insert your ETH price data here

df["bntp"] = insert your BNT price data here

df["k"] = your portfolio size / 2 * ((your portfolio size / 2) / 
*ETH price per BNT quantity at T0 (when you started becoming an LP)

df["ethq"] = df.apply(lambda x: ethq_amm_simulation(x.ethp, x.k), axis=1)

df["bntq"] = df.apply(lambda x: bntq_amm_simulation(x.ethq, x.k), axis=1)

df["LP Value"] = (df["ethp"] * df["ethq"]) + df["bntq"] * df["bntp"]

df["Hold Value"] = df["ethp"] * df["ethq"] at T0 (when you started 
becoming an LP) + (df["bntp"] * df["bntq"] at T0 (when you started 
becoming an LP)

df["Impermanent Loss"] = df["Hold Value"] - df["LP Value"]
```